# AJAX update in VAT amount in the Cart and Checkout page - Woocommerce

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a condition for adding VAT. If condition true then i need to update the VAT value (0). And My code is working well. But it needs to reload the page to know the value of updated VAT. How can i do it without reloading the page? My code is below:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review', 'cm_checkout_based_on_amount' );

function cm_checkout_based_on_amount( $post_data ) {
    WC()->customer->set_is_vat_exempt( false );
    parse_str( $post_data, $output );

    $minimum = 160;
    $county  = array('GB');
    $cart_tot_order = WC()->cart->total;

    if ( $cart_tot_order > $minimum && in_array( WC()->customer->get_shipping_country(), $county ) ){
        WC()->customer->set_is_vat_exempt( true );
    }
}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can either trigger a checkout/cart update with jQuery after these details are updated, or send custom data with the order review fragments.

To update cart/checkout trigger these:

```
// For checkout
$(document.body).trigger('update_checkout', { update_shipping_method: false });
// For cart
$(document.body).trigger('wc_update_cart');
```

To send custom fragments

```
add_filter('woocommerce_update_order_review_fragments', 'custom_wc_fragments');
function custom_wc_fragments($fragments)
{
   ob_start();
   echo 'Updated content here';
   $updated_content = ob_get_clean();
   $selector_of_the_element_you_want_to_update = '#order_review';
   $fragments[$selector_of_the_element_you_want_to_update] = $updated_content;

   return $fragments;
}
```

**Note:** these codes will not work out of the box, but they are a start to how you'll approach this.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried to trigger your given js. But it won't work. It will update the value of total amount but i need the update of VAT amount in the cart & checkout page. Is there any trigger method for update VAT?